# Multiple ViewComponents ids in one View in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

This is my simple ViewVomponent:

```
@model string
<input type="text" id="nameId" value="@Model" placeholder="Name...">
```

It is very simple and common, there is no use it.

The problem appears, when I'm trying to use many ViewComponents in one View, e. g.:

```
@(await Component.InvokeAsync("NameViewComponent", "some name"))
@(await Component.InvokeAsync("NameViewComponent", "some name1"))
@(await Component.InvokeAsync("NameViewComponent", "some name2"))
//etc...
```

It has ambiguity between input ids, which prevents them from using by other code in View.

How should I do with ids problem in many ViewComponents in one View?

Comment: You need to pass in something that represents the unique id.  Consider changing your model to take both an id and a string.

Comment: @DavidL I've been thinking about generating unique guids, but it requires a lot of auxiliary code, we need to generate guid for EVERYTHING! unique  in viewcomponent, ids, js functions, etc...